# Windows server 2003 ipsec error

Tags: ipsec, windows-server-2003-r2

I have a Windows Server 2003 domain controller and a bunch of clients. Something happened and now IPSec service fails on the server. After IPSec fails to start, all TCP/IP traffic is blocked to the server. I disables IPSec service and now I can access the server but only from clients that are NOT in the domain. If I try to access the server from a domain member, it doesn't even respont to ping (while it is readily availabe even if I log in on the same PC with a local user).

Is there a way to totally disable IPSec? I don't really need that kind of security as this is a small business and we don't have any confidental information, so I don't care if traffic is not encrypted or so. I just want the domain members to be able to access the server and I want to aviod reinstalling the server at any cost.